# I don't really understand the purpose of brackets enclosing code

Tags: java

I'm just playing with integer arrays and find that the following won't compile with multiple errors:

```
   public class GetData{
   int[]       arr = new int[5];
   arr[0] = 30;
                    }
```

But if I add some brackets around the code it compiles:

```
   public class GetData{
   {
   int[]       arr = new int[5];
   arr[0] = 30;
   }                    }
```

Probably there is something fundamental that I'm not understanding.
I don't why the first code section won't compile.

Comment: Because you can't put arbitrary statements directly inside a class. They need to be inside a method or an initialiser block. That's what you have in your second code.

Comment: You've constructed an initializer block, which is almost certainly not what you meant to do. Take a look at literally any Java tutorial ever. The first thing they ever have you write is `public static void main(String[] args)`.

Comment: On a semi-related note, either your spacebar is broken or your IDE was written by Satan himself. You're going to want to adopt a reasonable coding standard for spacing and indenting your code, or nobody (least of all you) will be able to read what you're doing once you write more than ten lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A class can't just contain code. It can only contain:

- Classes (so-called inner classes)
- Semi-colons. These don't do anything, but `class Foo { ;;; }` compiles.
- methods.
- field declarations.
- Initializers.
- Constructors.

And of course comments, which can appear anywhere.

Crucially, `int[] arr = new int[5];` **is a field declaration** and therefore legal: It declares a field named `arr`, of type `int[]`, with an initializing expression.

`arr[0] = 30;` on the other hand, is an assignment expression, which is code. Which isn't legal here. You need to shove that in a method or constructor or some such.

`{}` inside a class is an exotic java construct, rarely used: The instance initializer. It's very similar to a constructor.

That explains why your second snippet does compile: The first batch of brackets defines 'these are the brackets that surround the content of this class definition', and the brackets inside of that define: "This brackets code which is an instance initializer". `arr[0] = 30;` is legal in them, but this isn't java code you'd ordinarily put out there, this stuff should go in a method:

```
public class GetData /* not a good name! */ {
    public void doStuff() {
        int[] arr = new int[5];
        arr[0] = 30;
    }
}
```

Compiles just fine.